# PlaySound in c++ works only when run with VS

Tags: c++, winapi

This is my simple code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <mmsystem.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int num;
    cout << "Insert number: " << endl;
    cin >> num;
    if (num == 1) PlaySound(TEXT("C:\\filePATH\\Sound_Fail.wav"), NULL, SND_FILENAME);
}
```

and I followed [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2Fqh-8XqK0M) to get it. Now if I run the code directly from VS using ctrl+F5 the sound is nicely played. But if use my explorer and search for the compiled (.exe) file and run it from there the sound does not play.

The question is why and how to correct that?

Comment: I would guess that `PlaySound` defaults to asynchronous operation, and that it's cut short when the process terminates. However I do not see how the process can survive longer when you run this from Visual Studio. I think that means that your description is not entirely accurate.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I'm quite new to c++ and I kinda have no idea what this means exactly.

Comment: `PlaySound` is just a synchronous call that doesn't require a message loop (and that wouldn't explain, why it runs from Visual Studio anyway). The only reason why this could fail is that you are either using a relative path name or the file is inaccessible unless the process is launched from Visual Studio.

Comment: `PlaySound()` is synchronous by default. If the `SND_ASYNC` flag is specified, it plays asynchronously, otherwise `SND_SYNC` is assumed and it plays synchronously. Per the documentation: "*If the function cannot find the specified sound and the `SND_NODEFAULT` flag is not specified, `PlaySound` uses the default system event sound instead. If the function can find neither the system default entry nor the default sound, it makes no sound and returns FALSE.*"